# Boost python linking

Tags: c++, python, boost, hyperlink, cmake

I'm adding boost.python for my Game. I write wrappers for my classes to use them in scripts. The problem is linking that library to my app. I'm using `cmake` build system.

Now I have a simple app with 1 file and makefile for it:

```
PYTHON = /usr/include/python2.7

BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

TARGET = main

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python \
    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 \
    -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON) -I$(BOOST_INC) -c -fPIC $(TARGET).cpp
```

And this works. It builds a 'so' file for me which I can import from python.

Now the question: how to get this for cmake?

I wrote in main `CMakeList.txt`:

```
...
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system date_time python REQUIRED)
message("Include dirs of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("Libs of boost: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ...
)

target_link_libraries(Themisto
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ...
)
...
```

`message` calls show:

```
Include dirs of boost: /usr/include
Libs of boost: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.a/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.a/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt.a
```

Ok, so I've added simple .cpp-file for my project with include of `<boost/python.hpp>`. I get an error at compiling:

```
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

So it doesn't take all need include directories.

And **second** question:

How to organize 2-step building of script-cpp files? In makefile I showed there are **TARGET.o** and **TARGET.so**, how to process that 2 commands in cmake?

As I understand, the best way is to create subproject and do something there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are missing your include directory and libs for python in your CMakeList.txt. Use the PythonFindLibs macro or the same find_package strategy you used for Boost

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system date_time python REQUIRED)
message("Include dirs of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("Libs of boost: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
message("Include dirs of Python: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("Libs of Python: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )

include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}  # <-------
        ...
)

target_link_libraries(Themisto
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} # <------
    ...
)
...
```

Comment: What to do if my project should be crossplatform? That line won't work at windows.

Comment: sorry! I try an up vote and I press the down. My apologies. I think you should post original - non cross-platform - answer too. I do some python/cython/c stuff and all I care is efficiency (in this project). Again, sorry for my stupid mouse (I know, only the users are stupid, never the tool ...)

Comment: @cox fixed this for you :)

Comment: @cox Visit the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5238644/revisions) to see what was changed. I have only changed the path to be platform agnostic instead of being unix based.