# Linking error with boost::python

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem getting started with Boost's python library. My code is

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>

namespace python=boost::python;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    python::dict global;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried a lot and the closest I get to a working program is a linking error with boost:

```
$ gcc -c $(python2.7-config --cflags)  bpt.cpp            
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
$ gcc bpt.o $(python2.7-config --ldflags) -o bpt
bpt.o: In Funktion `dict':
/usr/include/boost/python/dict.hpp:89: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `boost::python::detail::dict_base::dict_base()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed Boost through apt-get (libboost-all-dev) so gcc should find it, shouldn't it? I know that bjam is the preferred way to compile programs using boost::python, but as i just wanted the python interpreter for plotting purposes, i don't wanted to start up with Jamfile and boost-build.jam and so on. So what do I have to do to link against the library?

Comment: Boost.Python is not header only, you need to link to the library as well. Try adding `-lboost_python` to the gcc command line.

Comment: Thanks, that's the flag I was missing. Could you please state where i could have found that out by myself?

Comment: As far as I know CMake can do this for you as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5238644/147808.

Comment: @Praetorian why is your answer in a comment?

Comment: It should be listed somewhere in the Boost.Python docs (hopefully, Boost.Python is not the best when it comes to documentation)

Comment: @olovb Because I'm too lazy to look for a link to documentation that says linking is necessary. Without that it wouldn't be worthy of a proper answer (IMHO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Praetorian say you need to link with the proper library.

Add `-lboost_python` to the command line:

```
gcc bpt.o -lboost_python $(python2.7-config --ldflags) -o bpt
```

Unfortunately the boost-python documentation isn't very clear on the subject, but there is a general instruction for boost on how to link with their libraries: [how to link to a boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library).

Linking is necessary whenever you use a library that isn't header only.